# C# member variable initialization; best practice?

Tags: c#, constructor, declaration

Is it better to initialize class member variables on declaration

```
private List<Thing> _things = new List<Thing>();
private int _arb = 99;
```

or in the default constructor?

```
private List<Thing> _things;
private int _arb;

public TheClass()
{
  _things = new List<Thing>();
  _arb = 99;
}
```

Is it simply a matter of style or are there performance trade-offs, one way or the other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/best-practice-initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In terms of performance, there is no real difference; field initializers are implemented as constructor logic. The only difference is that field initializers happen before any "base"/"this" constructor.

The constructor approach can be used with auto-implemented properties (field initializers cannot) - i.e.

```
[DefaultValue("")]
public string Foo {get;set;}
public Bar() { // ctor
  Foo = "";
}
```

Other than that, I tend to prefer the field initializer syntax; I find it keeps things localized - i.e.

```
private readonly List<SomeClass> items = new List<SomeClass>();
public List<SomeClass> Items {get {return items;}}
```

I don't have to go hunting up and down to find where it is assigned...

The obvious exception is where you need to perform complex logic or deal with constructor parameters - in which case constructor-based initialization is the way to go. Likewise, if you have multiple constructors, it would be preferable for the fields to always get set the same way - so you might have ctors like:

```
public Bar() : this("") {}
public Bar(string foo) {Foo = foo;}
```

edit: as a side comment, note that in the above, if there are other fields (not shown) with field initializers, then they are only directly initialized in the constructors that call `base(...)` - i.e. the `public Bar(string foo)` ctor. The other constructor does *not* run field initializers, since it knows they are done by the `this(...)` ctor.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I have a question: What did you mean by "constructors that call base(...)"? you public Bar(string foo) {Foo = foo;} doesn't appear to be calling : base(), or does it happen implicitly? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Bruno for a `class`, every constructor has an implicit `: base()` unless you add something more specific - which could be `: base(123, "abc")`, or could be `: this(123, "abc")`.

Comment: @Marc So Is the initialization in the order (1)fieldInitializer(2)BaseConstructor(3)LocalConstructor

Answer (score 13):

Actually, field initializers as you demonstrate is a convenient shorthand. The compiler actually copies the initialization code into the beginning of each instance constructor that you define for your type.

This has two implications: first, any field initialization code is duplicated in each constructor and, second, any code you include in your constructors to initialize fields to specific values will in fact re-assign the fields.

So performance-wise, and with regards to compiled code size, you're better off moving field initializers into constructors.

On the other hand, the performance impact and code 'bloat' will usually be negligable, and the field initializer syntax has the important benefit of lessening the risk that you might forget to initialize some field in one of your constructors.

Comment: The performance point only applies if you re-assign the values (i.e. it doesn't apply in the original code). Likewise, the "bloat" issue (which is minuscule) only applies to ctors that call base(...) - so you can side-step this with a private ctor (as posted) - only this ctor will init the fields.

Comment: Do you know if this reassignment actually happens in practice? The compiler should be able to remove extra initializations, if it doesn't change the program semantics.

Answer (score 6):

One major limitation with field initializers is that there's no way to wrap them in a try-finally block.  If an exception is thrown in a field initializer, any resources that were allocated in previous initializers will be abandoned; there's no way to prevent it.  Other errors in construction can be dealt with, if awkwardly, by having a protected base constructor accept an IDisposable by reference, and pointing it at itself as its very first operation.  One can then avoid calling the constructor except through factory methods which in case of exception will call Dispose on the partially-created object.  This protection will allow for cleanup of IDisposables created in derived-class initializers if the main-class constructor fails after "smuggling out" a reference to the new object.  Unfortunately, there's no way to provide such protection if a field initializer fails.

Answer (score 3):

For instance variables, it is largely a matter of style (I prefer using a constructor). For static variables, there is a [performance benefit](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2004/04/17/115300.aspx) to initializing inline (not always possible, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Use either field initializers or create an Init() function.  The problem with putting these things in your constructor is that if you ever need to add a 2nd constructor, you end up with copy/paste code (or you overlook it and end up with uninitialized variables).

I would either initialize where declared.  Or have the constructor(s) call an Init() function.

Comment: Note the use of : this() to chain constructors in Marc Gravell's post above. This is a much better practice than writing separate Init()-functions.

Answer (score 1):

It's really up to you.
I often initialize them inline, cause I don't like having a constructor when I don't really need one (I like small classes !).

Answer (score 0):

On added point to the above - You always have a constructor when implementing classes that have an implementation.  If you do not declare one then the default instructor is inferred by the compiler [public Foo(){}]; a constructor that takes no arguments.

Often times I like to offer both approaches.  Allow constructors for those that wish to use them and allow the Field Initializers for situations where you wish to use a simplified or default implementation of your class / type.  This adds flexibility to your code.  Keep in mind that anyone can use the default field initializer if they choose ... be sure to declare it manually if you offer more than one constructor - public Foo(){}