# Do I need two new List<ParentDetail>() constructors?

Tags: c#, list

I have the following class called Parent. It contains a list of ParentDetail classes:

```
public class Parent
{

    public Parent()
    {
       this._parentDetails = new List<ParentDetail>();
    }

    public IList<ParentDetail> ParentDetails
    {
        get { return _parentDetails; }
    }

    private List<ParentDetail> _parentDetails = new List<ParentDetail>();

}

public class ParentDetail
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

The class seems to work but I don't understand why "= new List();" appears twice. Can someone explain in a couple of lines what is happening?

Comment: who says you need to initialize _parentDetails twice ?  You do not.

Comment: That seems to be redundant, either in constructor or inline but both is needless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
private List<ParentDetail> _parentDetails;
public Parent()
{
   this._parentDetails = new List<ParentDetail>();
}
```

Excellent explanation [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298183/c-member-variable-initialization-best-practice)

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need two new List()
>   constructors?

No, one of them would be enough - creating two instaces of which one will never be used is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

This is redundancy, which is not needed.
Either one of them can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to, and shouldn't.  In this case `_parentDetails` is initialised twice.

Both the assignments are equivalent in this case.  For what it's worth I prefer initiailising in the default constructor, not the field/member declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the inline creation of `new List<ParentDetail>();` is needed as it is already done inside your constructor..Or else you can remove the constructor as a whole...

The inline code when compiled creates a default constructor and moves that piece of code inside the constructor.