# Why to create private variable of DBContext and initialize it to public constructor of a class?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

As I was learning ASP.NET on Youtube, an author created an instance of `DBContext` by creating private variable of type `DBContext` and initialize it to public constructor of a class:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext context;

    public CustomerController()
    {
       context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

}
```

So, my question is would it be the same if I just create private instance of `DBContext`, that is,

```
private ApplicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

Please can you explain why the author decided to create instance of `DBContext` as shown above and what is the benefit of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# member variable initialization; best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298183/c-sharp-member-variable-initialization-best-practice)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a practice to follow, there is not any particular reason. My preference would be to initialize in the constructor if it's being changed from the constructor, otherwise assign on initialization.

Edit :

following are initializations are same :

private ApplicationDbContext context;

```
public CustomerController()
{
   context = new ApplicationDbContext();
}
```

AND

```
private ApplicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

But eventually, at some point, you will have your constructor overloaded as follows :

```
 public CustomerController(IService1 service1, IService2 service2)
    {
       // initialization here probably using DI
       // so it will looks consistant if you keep initialization at one place
       context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Anupam, thank you for your reply, please could you clarify and give clearer explanation. Thank you for your undertanding and attention