# java class member initialisation

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

I am a bit ashamed to ask that, being a Java programmer for years, but here goes:
Is there a difference between allocating objects during construction, and doing so directly when declaring the relevant field? That is, is there a difference between the following two:

```
public class MyClass{
    MyObj obj=new MyObj();
}
```

AND

```
public class MyClass{
    MyObj obj;
    public MyClass() {
        obj=new MyObj();
    }
}
```

Of course, I assume this specific init's do not rely on outside parameters.

Comment: There is nothing to be ashamed of. Everyone learns here!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> instance variable initialization done **before** constructor call
>
> Its **not good to do.**
> You can restrict user from call of const. if you want to perform certain operation before initialization.

**Best Practice:**

> 1. Don't initialize with the default values in declaration (null, false, 0, 0.0...).
> 2. Prefer initialization in declaration if you don't have a constructor parameter that changes the value of the field.
> 3. If the value of the field changes because of a constructor parameter put the >initialization in the constructors.
> 4. Be consistent in your practice. (the most important rule)

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/best-practice-initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration)

Comment: Also with static variable/method calls you can generate a NullPointerException if the variable is not initialized until the constructor.

Comment: I would dispute that *any* of those rules is "best practice".  None of them significantly effect code readability, and that's the only thing that really matters here.

Comment: Code readibility is not only concern i think, I feel it is best for me atleast. and ofcourse any of the java programmer will go for const. first to read the code.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. Except that if you add multiple constructors you'll have duplicate code.

An alternative is to use an initializer block

```
{
   var = 1;
}
```

Reference: [Initializing Fields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)