# Where it is better to initialize field?

Tags: java, android

Where it is better to initialize fields? In **constructor (var.1)** or on **declaration (var.2)**?

**var. 1**

```
public class UtilWebLoading {
private int data;
private Context context;

public UtilWebLoading(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    data = 100;
}
...
}
```

**var. 2**

```
public class UtilWebLoading {
private int data = 100;
private Context context;

public UtilWebLoading(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
...
}
```

Comment: I think you should look for a better example e.g. a list member with no constructor parameters, because in this case there is no real choice, since example 2 is wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Practice: Initialize class fields in constructor or at declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/best-practice-initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In var. 1 the context has been initiated, while in var. 2 it will be null!
Use the first one.

Comment: It won't run, but if he would place Context context on top of the Util in var 2. it would run, but with null value.

Answer (score 4):

I personally prefer to initialize fields when I have *sufficient context* to do so. For example, if I have a `List` field I usually initialize it upon declaration (unless the class requires the user to pass an implementation of their choosing), but if I have an array that requires a size to be passed, I'm forced to wait for a constructor call.

Hence, in your case, the second snippet *does not have enough context* to initialize `Util` at declaration, because no valid `Context` member exists.