# using default constructor to initialize types C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Practice: Initialize class fields in constructor or at declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/best-practice-initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration)

Please do you have any advantage for doing

```
public class MyClass
{
  List<string> list;
  public MyClass
  {
     list = new List<string>();
  }
}
```

over doing this

```
public class MyClass
{
  List<string> list = new List<string>();
  public MyClass
  {

  }
}
```

I guess its all the same. Thus constructors are more important than these simple cases

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are choosing exactly when the list is initialised.  If there is other code in the constructor you are responsible for positioning the initialisation in the right place.

Also if the class has a base class, then the base class constructors will be called before your list is initialised.

Answer (score 0):

First all the initializers run in order from derived to base, and then all the constructors  run in order from base to derived.

Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one.aspx) article by Eric Lippert.