# Setting variables in constructor vs definition

Tags: c#, class, declaration

Observe the following...

```
//pattern 1
public class Cheesesteak
{
    public string bread {get; private set}
    public string cheese {get; private set}

    public Cheesesteak()
    {
        bread = "Amoroso"; 
        cheese = "Cheez Whiz";
    }
}

//pattern 2
public class Cheesesteak
{
    public string bread 
    {
        get {return bread;}
        set 
        {
            bread = "Amoroso";
        }
    }
    public string cheese 
    {
        get {return cheese;}
        set
        {
            cheese = "Cheez Whiz";
        }
    }
    public Cheesesteak() {}
}
```

This is a curiosity question. Is there any advantage or particular reason that you would set the variables in the definition of the "set" versus declaring them in the constructor? My initial guess is pattern 1 is shorter, but less efficient during compile.

Comment: Pattern 2 is a stack overflow.

Comment: @SLaks ..that seems appropriate given the name of this site? :P

Comment: Flagged as duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/best-practice-initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration   Please read the comments/answers there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any advantage or particular reason that you would set the variables in the definition of the "set" versus declaring them in the constructor?

No, and in fact, this is probably not what you want at all.  This will make it impossible to set "break" or "cheese", as any call, such as `bread = "rye";`, would set it to "Amoroso" (if it worked, but will cause a `StackOverflowException`).  Also note that trying to retrieve the value in your code will cause a `StackOverflowException`, and the property getter returns the *property* and not a backing field value.

You were likely thinking of this:

```
public class Cheesesteak
{
    private string bread = "Amoroso";
    public string Bread 
    {
        get {return bread;}
        set 
        {
            bread = value;
        }
    }

    // ...
```

The only advantage here is you're setting the "default" value where the field is defined, which can help with maintainability or readability in some cases, and even potentially eliminate the need for a defined constructor, which might reduce the overall length of code.

> My initial guess is pattern 1 is shorter, but less efficient during compile.

In general, setting the fields inline vs. setting them in a constructor does not make this less efficient.  The compiler will cause the type's actual constructor to set the fields first then run the constructor code, so both versions end up (for practical purposes) the same in terms of the compiled IL.  This isn't a matter of efficiency, but rather of code readability and maintainability.

Note that, if you wanted the property to always be a constant (ie: `Bread` should **always** return `"Amoroso"`), you can just make the property have a getter and no setter:

```
public string Bread { get { return "Amoroso"; } }
```

I suspect this is not the case, but I thought I'd mention it as an option just in case it's what you intended.

Comment: @ReedCopsey In fact, both will cause an SOE. Both the getter and setter recurse on themselves infinitely.

Comment: @NominSim I rewrote to be explicit

Comment: @ReedCopsey +1 Didn't mean to be a pain as RobertHarvey says "arguing about broken code", just wanted to make sure the OP knew *how* broken it was.

Answer (score 1):

Well the second option will result in a `StackOverflowException` whenever a user tries to assign **or** access the properties, versus the first which will only allow private access to them.

You maybe meant something like:

```
private string bread = "Amaroso";
public string Bread
{
    get { return bread; }
    private set
    {
        bread = value;
    }
}
```

Which will initialize the property with "Amaroso" but will not allow it to be set publicly.

Comment: And also when the user tries to retrieve the property value.  Both accessors are SOE traps waiting to explode.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are completely different.  The `get` and `set` blocks are actually methods that get executed when the property is read from or written to.  Nether of them have *anything* to do with initialization.

```
var x = thing.Property; // Property's "get" accessor method is executed
thing.Property = x; // Property's "set" accessor method is executed
```

In your second example, both property accessors will infinitely recurse on themselves and you will get a StackOverflowException.