# Is the default constructor necessary?

Tags: c#

What is the difference between these two?

```
class Class1
{
    public int a = 1;
}

class Class2
{
    public int a;
    public Class2()
    {
        a = 1;
    }
}
```

If none, can I skip the default constructor and initialize my variables like in `Class1`?

Comment: It will make a difference in the _order_ that things happen.

Comment: I like putting initialization in the constructor because, if you do something more complicated and it fails, you'll get a more specific error than "failed on initialization."

Comment: What is the difference in order?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Practice: Initialize class fields in constructor or at declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/best-practice-initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific example, field initializers (`Class1`) are fine. Arguably, what *isn't* fine is the public field ;p I would advise either:

```
// manually implemented property with field-initializer
private int a = 1;
public int A { get { return a;} set { a = value;} }
```

or:

```
// automatically implemented property with constructor-based initialization
public int A {get;set;}
public Class1() {
    A = 1;
}
```

[@hvd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16651041/23354) correctly states the difference. To illustrate a concrete example of where this can give different results, see the following. The main take-away message from this example is really "be very very careful when using `virtual` methods from constructors".

Output first:

```
Class1: 1
Class2: 0
```

Code:

```
using System;
abstract class SomeBaseClass {
    protected abstract void Write();
    protected SomeBaseClass() {
        Console.Write(GetType().Name + ": ");
        Write();
    }
}
class Class1 : SomeBaseClass {
    protected override void Write() {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
    public int a = 1;
}

class Class2 : SomeBaseClass {
    protected override void Write() {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
    public int a;
    public Class2() {
        a = 1;
    }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        new Class1();
        new Class2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Calling `new Class1()` first sets `a` to `1`, then calls the base class constructor.

Calling `new Class2()` first calls the base class constructor, then sets `a` to `1`.

Since you're deriving from `object`, the base class constructor does nothing. In other cases, it might make a difference.

Answer (score 8):

You won't notice the difference in your code, but the difference is the order in which things are called and initialized:

1. Derived class field initializers are run.
2. Base class field initializers are run.
3. Base class constructor is run.
4. Derived class constructor is run.

So, in your `Class1` the field is initialized in step 1. In your `Class2` the field is initialzed to its default value of 0 in step 1, and then set to 1 in step 4.

More information in Eric Lippert's article series [Why do initializers run in the opposite order as constructors, part 1](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one.aspx), [part 2](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in the order between constructor call and 'a' field setting, as you can see in the IL for each class:

**Class1**

```
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0002:  stfld      int32 SandBox.Class1::a
  IL_0007:  ldarg.0
  IL_0008:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_000d:  ret
```

**Class2**

```
.maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  ldarg.0
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0008:  stfld      int32 SandBox.Class2::a
  IL_000d:  ret
```

Comment: for info, it is probably worth using "release" / "optimized" mode when snagging IL output - debug builds sometimes have noticeable differences (the "nop"s are the big clue that this is a debug build)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use initialization for every field, or for automatic properties. The constructor gives you the ability to set values for those fields and properties.

It should be noted that field initialization is prepended to *each* constructor in a class, by the way, so writing a default constructor (and having all other constructors for a class continue from it) may be more efficient from a code-size perspective. This is a way that the default constructor could really come in handy.