# Private field initialisation with full properties

Tags: c#, properties, coding-style

Just a quick look-and-feel question... is it acceptable to initialize the private fields of full properties right there where you declare them, or would the average developer curse my name for not putting it in the constructor?

```
private int _linesDataGridHeight = 300;
public int LinesDataGridHeight
{
    get { return _linesDataGridHeight; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _linesDataGridHeight, value); }
}

private bool _isHideLinesCheckboxChecked = false;
public bool IsHideLinesCheckboxChecked
{
    get { return _isHideLinesCheckboxChecked; }
    set
    {
        this.LinesDataGridHeight = value ? 0 : 300;
        SetProperty(ref _isHideLinesCheckboxChecked, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: My preference is in the constructor, especially if you're doing this for multiple properties.  This makes it easier for the eye to catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think mostly this comes down to personal preference since in C# it doesn't really matter. I prefer to initialise everything in the constructor because there I can see all my initialised values in one place. Also, there might be a rule set by your development team for an agreed standard for this.

This seems to be a similar post to another SO question, see here: [Initialize class fields in constructor or at declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/best-practice-initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration)