# Initialize string properties to String.Empty

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that has around 30 string properties in `.Net 4.0`. I need all of them to be initialized as Empty String. Currently I am writing this logic in constructor. Is there any better way for doing this ***with lesser number of lines of code***?

**REFERENCES**

1. [msdn - DefaultValueAttribute  Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx)

CODE

```
public class MakeHoldDetail
{
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public string Loc { get; set; }

    //constructor
    public MakeHoldDetail()
    {
        Supplier = String.Empty;
        Loc = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to initialize auto-properties as String.Empty, which there exists no shortcut syntax for. How are the questions any different other than the value you're trying to initialize them with (which is irrelevant)?

Comment: @Lijo Read this: [Best Practice: Initialize class fields in constructor or at declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/best-practice-initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration)