# Java EE - Entity getters doing minimal logic

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, entity

I'm working on a java enterprise application using JPA.I'll explain my doubt showing an example.

My EntityA has a field (that gets persisted in a dabase using a join table) representing a list of EntityB as follows.

```
public class EntityA {

private List<EntityB> listOfB;

*getter and setter for listOfB*

}
```

I don't want my getter for listOfB to return null in any case.
What is the best point in the code where I can initialize listOfB if it's null?

The first solution I thought about was modifying the getter:

```
public List<EntityB> getListOfB(){
   if(listOfB == null)
      listOfB = new ArrayList<EntityB>();

   return listOfB;
}
```

Then I considered using a method marked with @PostConstruct:

```
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
   if(listOfB == null)
      listOfB = new ArrayList<EntityB>();
}
```

I guess another option would be modifying the constructor.

What is the best approach? More than everything I'm asking this because I don't want any issue to happen due to the interaction with the JPA functionalities. I's also like to know about any issues that the three previously mentioned solutions could originate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
public class EntityA {
    private List<EntityB> listOfB = new ArrayList<EntityB>();
```

JPA Tools now generates Entities from tables in this manner and this works fine with JPA.

---

This is a very nice solution, if you just want to make sure, that the List is initialized (and thus not null). JPA tools seems to take this a bit further and initializes all references to other Entities. EG:

```
@Entity
public class Entity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private OtherEntity otherEntity = new OtherEntity ();

    private Set<EntityTwo> entityTwos= new HashSet<EntityTwo>(0);
```

I would agree, that initializing Lists or Sets (OneToMany) makes sense, since the List can be empty. Initializing an Object of another entity is a bit strange (OneToOne, ManyToOne), since the reference could be non existing. But that is what JPA tool generates.

---

### Entity getters doing minimal logic

A **Getter** is definitely the wrong place for this. In your example the getter changes the state of the object, which is something you wouldn't expect from a getter.

Initializing field in **@PostConstruct** is a viable solution. But I would prefer it for initializing fields with a specific value or with some more logic.

Comment: Thanks for the input, that is also a viable solution. But on the other hand, I still don't understand why your solution is better than any of the ones I suggested. Do you have any explanation for that?

Comment: It has better readability and less overhead. But this would be a whole new discussion:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/best-practice-initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/best-practice-initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration)