# Set default values by script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm not able to set default values by script  (instead of inspector) because there is `MeshRenderer`, a `RigiBody` etc. These are not numerical values.

Comment: What is your problem? The fields are already set.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Reset` method instead of Start/Awake is a better way to initialize your component with default values (only if the default values are not related to game settings at runtime).

Use `Awake` if you want to initialize your fields at runtime/gametime. And use `Start` for all the `GetComponent` logic. Because `Start` is called after `Awake` and makes sure that all other components in the scene are properly initialized before you call `GetComponent` to find them.

**Edit: Example monobehaviour with reset.**

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Name;
    public float Health;
    public float Armor;

    void Reset()
    {
        Name = "UNKNOWN";
        Health = 100;
        Armor = 0;
    }

}
```

Then add this component to a `GameObject` in Unity. You'll notice these values with be automatically set. If you ever want to reset this component: right-click and reset.

[image]

Comment: Yes, `Reset` seems to be the way to go. Can you edit your answer with an example of `Reset` applied in a script? I'm not sure how to use it...

Answer (score 0):

Just like you can initialize a primitive value in the script you can also do it with objects like this:

```
public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public int Velocity = 0;
    public Vector2 Position = new Vector2(0, 0);

    void Start(){
        ...
    }

    void Update(){
        ...
    }
}
```

But you can only instantiate objects, if you need to modify it in some way you should use the Start/Awake methods.

Read more about this here: [Initialize class fields in constructor or at declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/best-practice-initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration)