# Trying to understand static constructors

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand need for static constructors. None of information I found answered following question I have. Why would you do this

```
class SimpleClass
{
    // Static variable that must be initialized at run time.
    static readonly long baseline;

    // Static constructor is called at most one time, before any
    // instance constructor is invoked or member is accessed.
    static SimpleClass()
    {
        baseline = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    }
}
```

as opposed to this

```
class SimpleClass
{
    // Static variable that must be initialized at run time.
    static readonly long baseline = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

    // Static constructor is called at most one time, before any
    // instance constructor is invoked or member is accessed.
    //static SimpleClass()
    //{

    //}
}
```

?

---

This is not dupe of other question, this is about static constructors which don't accept parameters.

Comment: This is not static specific question, the question is valid for non static initialisation too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize class fields in constructor or at declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration)

Comment: @CyrilGandon That is not a dupe - this is about static constructors which don't accept parameters. Consider removing the dupe tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The need is somehow obvious: You want to do more than some field initialization for your static members.

Logically if you have this class:

```
class SimpleClass
{
    // Static variable that must be initialized at run time.
    static readonly long baseline = DateTime.Now.Ticks;


}
```

You can re-write it to have the same effect:

```
class SimpleClass
{
    // Static variable that must be initialized at run time.
    static readonly long baseline;

    static SimpleClass () {
        baseline = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    }   
}
```

But instead, you could do more in your static constructor such as inspecting (using reflection) some properties and emiting some fast accessors / getters to them, or just simple notify other systems that your type has been created, etc.

From Jeffrey Richter CLR via C# book:

> When the C# compiler sees a class with static fields that use inline
>   initialization (the BeforeFieldInit class), the compiler emits the
>   class’s type definition table entry with the BeforeFieldInit metadata
>   flag. When the C# compiler sees a class with an explicit type
>   constructor (the Precise class), the compiler emits the class’s type
>   definition table entry without the BeforeFieldInit metadata flag. The
>   rationale behind this is as follows: initialization of static fields
>   needs to be done before the fields are accessed, whereas an explicit
>   type constructor can contain arbitrary code that can have observable
>   side effects; this code may need to run at a precise time.

Obviouselly there is something more than this happening behind the scenes, I would suggest you to read entire chapter from CLR via C#: "Type Constructors"

Comment: Well, they're not quite the same - a class with a static constructor can have different initialization timing compared with a class which only has static field initializers. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx

Comment: can you show example why I need static constructor, what can I do there I can't do in a field initialization?

Comment: @JonSkeet Maybe you can answer

Comment: @user200312: Well, the core of the answer here is right: "You want to do more than some field initialization for your static members." For example, maybe you want to log the fact that the type is being initialized.

Comment: "Obviouselly there is something much interesting happening behind the scenes" I don't think that's obvious when you only specified it in terms of a translation. That makes it sound like the two versions are equivalent, when they're not.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a possible difference:

```
class SimpleClass
{
    static readonly long A = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    static readonly long B = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

    static SimpleClass()
    {
    }
}
```

`A` and `B` are not guaranteed to be the same value, though if you were to write it in the constructor, you could guarantee it:

```
class SimpleClass
{
    static readonly long A;
    static readonly long B;

    static SimpleClass()
    {
        var ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        A = ticks;
        B = ticks;
    }
}
```

In addition, *order matters* for instantiation of static members.

According to ECMA-334 regarding static field initialization:

> The static field variable initializers of a class declaration
>   correspond to a sequence of assignments that are executed in the
>   textual order in which they appear in the class declaration. If a
>   static constructor (§17.11) exists in the class, execution of the
>   static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that
>   static constructor. Otherwise, the static field initializers are
>   executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of
>   a static field of that class

So, we can write something like this:

```
class SimpleClass
{
   public static readonly long A = IdentityHelper.GetNext();
   public static readonly long B = IdentityHelper.GetNext();

   static SimpleClass()
   {
   }
}

public static class IdentityHelper
{
    public static int previousIdentity = 0;
    public static int GetNext()
    {
        return ++previousIdentity;
    }
}
```

Here, `A` is guaranteed to be assigned before `B`. In this example, `A` will be `1`, and `B` will be `2`. We can guarantee that `A` < `B` (assuming the identity does not overflow and there's no issues with threading). Now, if we re-order the fields:

```
public static readonly long B = IdentityHelper.GetNext();
public static readonly long A = IdentityHelper.GetNext();
```

The functionality *changes*. Thus, we've created a side-effect which is not immediately clear simply by re-ordering the fields definitions.

A more likely scenario is, we may want to do this:

```
class SimpleClass
{
   public static readonly long A = IdentityHelper.GetExpensiveResult().A;
   public static readonly long B = IdentityHelper.GetExpensiveResult().B;

   static SimpleClass()
   {
   }
}
```

Here, we're unable to share `GetExpensiveResult()` between the fields.

Comment: A tiny spot of the code that not related to the question, `return ++currentIdentity` is better, otherwise you will always have `IdentityHelper.currentIdentity == IdentityHelper.GetNext()`

Comment: @Danny Chen, could you elaborate on your last comment ; I'm not quite sure I understand how it worked

Comment: We can guarantee that A > B- maybe reverse? Not sure I followed that part though

Comment: @user200312 Sorry yes, you're right - it was a typo. Should be `A` < `B`

Comment: @Zil check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i), it's about c, but c# is the same.