# c# Initializers vs constructors

Tags: c#

I'm currently working through some old code and I started to wonder,  is there actually any difference between:

```
public class XmlExport : IXmlExport
{
    private readonly IJobRepository jobRepository = new JobRepository();
}
```

and

```
public class XmlExport : IXmlExport
{
    private readonly IJobRepository jobRepository;

    public XmlExport()
    {
        jobRepository = new JobRepository();
    }
}
```

Are there any advantages to initializing inside the constructor?  or is it just the same code?

Comment: The first option might be a better choice in case you have several independent constructors and you want to factorize the repo creation

Comment: There are differences: 1. When you initialize using the constructor, you can pass parameters to the `JobRepository` that are unknown at compile time. 2. When you have multiple constructors, inline initialization might be a better choice, because you don't need to chain the constructors or initialize in each one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question already has answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24558/7571171), I just wanted to add my 2p.

---

If in your example

```
public class XmlExport : IXmlExport
{
    private readonly IJobRepository jobRepository = new JobRepository();
}
```

the `JobRepository` constructor throws an exception, you will get

> the application is in break mode.

---

However, if the `jobRepository` is initialized in the constructor like this

```
public class XmlExport : IXmlExport
{
    private readonly IJobRepository jobRepository;

    public XmlExport()
    {
        jobRepository = new JobRepository();
    }
}
```

---

you will get the exact exception, stack trace, etc. This is also the only location where you can actually *catch* the exception.

---

Therefore, in my opinion it is better to initialize

- simple objects (`int`, `bool`, types you know won't throw) on declaration
- objects that might throw in the constructor.

Comment: Exception handling is a really good point - thanks.

Comment: @Lobsterpants thank you for your feedback & the accepted answer. I just recently came across this issue when I initialized WPF `Image`s at declaration instead of in the constructor. Generally, constructors shouldn't throw, but it's better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 2):

one advantage of using at constructor level , is you can pass dependency from outside and change your code easily.

you can do this

```
public class XmlExport : IXmlExport
{
    private readonly IJobRepository _jobRepository;

    public XmlExport(IJobRepository jobRepository)
    {
        _jobRepository = jobRepository;
    }
}
```

this is called as `Dependency injection` termed as `Constructor Level Dependancy` Injection.

I don't like declare and initialize field at class level it , and i don't see advantage of doing it. If you want to do initialization than Constructor is in class it for that purpose only , this is as per my reading of C++ book.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually preparing the code for dependency injection and the code will eventually look like that.  My first pass is to get everything initialized at the top of the module.

Comment: While I agree that DI is a good idea, this does not really answer the question.