# Difference between instance the list in the property and in the constructor

Tags: c#, object, oop

I need to know  what is the best and efficent way to instance the new List on a property and why?

Option one

```
public class ObjectA
{
   public List<ObjectB> MyList { get; set; } = new List<ObjectB>();
}
```

Option two

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public List<ObjectB> MyList { get; set; } 

    public ObjectA()
    {
        this.MyList = new List<ObjectB>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar with lot of explanation :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration

Comment: Suggested reading: **[Guidelines for Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections)**

Comment: I think it's not the duplicated of initialization of values, rather it's about the location of field object instantiation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though there are multiple explanations, I will attempt based on my understanding using the IL code of various scenarios.

1. **Instantiate the list in the constructor**

In this case, when the object is constructed by this constructor it would first make a call to **instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()** and then construct the list

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
    public ObjectA()
    {
        this.MyList = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

[image]

2. **Instantiate the list at the declaration**

In this case, when the object is constructed it would first **construct the list** and then make a call to the default constructor **instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()** and then initialize the list

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

[image]

3. **Instantiate the list at the declaration but the class has one constructor**

In this case, compiler has injected the code for the list instantiation in the constructor

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public ObjectA()
    {

    }
}
```

[image]

4. **Instantiate the list at the declaration, and create the class with different constructor**

In this case we can see the compiler has injected the code for the list instantiation in the new constructor too

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public ObjectA(int x)
    {

    }
}
public class ObjectB:ObjectA
{
    public ObjectB(int x):base(x)
    {
        
    }
}
```

[image]

5. **Instantiate the list at the declaration, calss has two constructors and a derived class**

In this case, the compiler injected the list instantiation code in both the constructors. *This would not happen in the case where we
instantiate the list in the constructor*

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public ObjectA()
    {

    }
    public ObjectA(int x)
    {

    }
}
public class ObjectB:ObjectA
{
    public ObjectB(int x):base(x)
    {
        
    }
}
```

[image]

> To summarise, In case of lists or similar objects if you have multiple constructors. It's developer's responsibility to ensure all required objects are initialized before the use. The complexity increases when this class gets derived. If we follow the clean code practices, smaller classes I would go with initiaize at declaration. But if the field objects are going to be big, doing some work at their construction, I would initialize them when required (This requires safety)